# Expected Identifier with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c

I have a block of code that calls an NSTimer from a singleton class. this is Viewcontroller.m

```
-(IBAction) start
{
[[[ApplicationManager instance].ticker [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0     target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
```

I have an error that says: Expected identifier
Can anyone see why? or where i can add something to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to get a book on Objective-C because this is all kinds of messed up. The code should look something like this. (at least if you're trying to do what I think you are)

```
- (IBAction) start
{
    [ApplicationManager instance].ticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

You had extraneous brackets at the beginning of the line, the beginning of the timer instance and at the end of the line, you were missing the statement's closing brace, and there was no equal sign between ticker and [NSTimer..

Comment: I have shivers thinking on what `ApplicationManager` could be

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Well, considering the timer property, I'm assuming some sort of bomb!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a typo in there. YESS should be YES

Comment: That is a typo transferring it to the site. thanks for the heads up. Edited the question.